# Android Share intent - issue with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I need to share text and one image from my application via a share intent. I read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) article. I thought it would be easy to create share intent. But it is not so easy, because there is a problem with sharing via Facebook.

I need to share some text and one image, which is stored in device. My first attempt looked like this:

**The first try**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/img.jpg")));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My custom text...");
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.label_share)));
```

I tried this code and in applications like Gmail, Google+, Google Keep, etc, everything works fine. But Facebook did not work fine.

[image]

There is no my text (`"My custom text..."`) in this screenshot. So I have tried something else.

**The second try**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/img.jpg")));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My custom text...");
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.label_share)));
```

And the result of this is here:

[image]

There is no text and also no image in this screenshot.

I also tried to change type to `image/*` and `*/*`, but it did not help. I do not know what is wrong. I just need to share some text and image via Facebook. The *first try* works well for other applications, but for Facebook not.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is OK, Facebook does not allow sharing text this way, they say "Pre-filling these fields erodes the authenticity of the user voice."